# Express/Passport: adminpanel authorization

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Is there any way to make authorization system like this:

```
app.get('/admin/*', function (req, res) {
    /*checks if user authorised, if not throws an error, if yes opens requested page*/
});

app.get('/admin/item', function (req, res) {
    /*blah-blah-blah*/
});

app.get('/admin/category', function (req, res) {
    /*blah-blah-blah*/
});
```

As an example I logged in and want to open `/admin/item` page.

I can simply get what do I want by this way, but this way generates more code:

```
app.get('/admin/item', function (req, res) {
    /*authorization check*/
    /*blah-blah-blah*/
});

app.get('/admin/category', function (req, res) {
    /*authorization check*/
    /*blah-blah-blah*/
});
```

Comment: You can find an example using passport [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/tree/master/examples/express3)

Comment: You don't understand my problem. I'm already using passportjs.

Comment: I've created a gist here https://gist.github.com/mmjmanders/8555670. This way only one method is added and no more extra code in the router is required.

Comment: It checks if user is aunthenticated, if not not redirects to `/login` page. But I want such functionality: when I request `/admin/item` it checks if I aunthenticated, if it's true it will open `/admin/item` page, if not redirect me to `/login` page. Make this functionality for all admin routes, I don't want to check it in each route.

Comment: I updated the gist, forgot a leading slash in the route. That's what the `/admin/:name` does, it does this for `/admin/item`, `/admin/category` and so on...

Comment: I simply want to redirect to page user wanted to open, and do not want to output anything. I have many admin routes, each route contains different action...